# Java - Using the output of one method in the statement body of another method is not producing the expected result

Tags: java, list, methods, arraylist, io

I have 2 classes, `LotSelection` and `LotGen`, in a package called `lotterynumberselector`. `LotSelection` has 2 methods: `LotPool()` and `WinningSequence()`. `LotPool()` is meant to return an ArrayList of 50 integers from 0 to 49 and scramble it. `WinningSequence()` is meant to create a 6-element array containing the first 6 integers from the ArrayList generated in LotPool().

This is the code for `LotSelection`.

```
package lotterynumberselector;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class LotSelection {

ArrayList<Integer> LotPool() {
    ArrayList<Integer> sequencedraw = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int i = 0; i < 49; i++) {
          sequencedraw.add(i);
    }
    Collections.shuffle(sequencedraw);
    return sequencedraw;
}

int[] WinningSequence() {
    int[] WinningSequence = new int[6];
    int j = 0;
    while (j < 6) {
        WinningSequence[j] = LotPool().get(j);
        j++;
    }
    return WinningSequence;
}

}
```

The purpose of `LotGen` is to test if the outputs created by `LotSelection` were doing their expected tasks. However, the output from WinningSequence() didn't match the first six numbers created from LotPool() and I'm wondering why. I'm not sure if it's because the code in `LotGen` or `LotSelection` is creating an unexpected result. I suspect it's because `LotPool()` is producing one 50-element ArrayList and `WinningSequence()` is creating ANOTHER `LotPool()` so it's making it's array from a DIFFERENT 50-element ArrayList, but I'm not sure.

Here is the code for `LotGen`:

```
package lotterynumberselector;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class LotGen {

public static void main(String [] args) {

    LotSelection a = new LotSelection();
    ArrayList<Integer> LotPool = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    LotPool = a.LotPool();
    System.out.println(LotPool);

    int[] WinSeq = new int[6];
    WinSeq = a.WinningSequence();
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(WinSeq));

}

}
```

Comment: First of all, respect java naming conventions and lowercase the first letter of your methods. Also, give them appropriate access modifiers.

Comment: can u share the output please

Comment: you are calling 6 times `lotPool` method, may be you want to store it in a variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this is very simple: each time you pick a new number for the list returned by `WinningSequence`, you call `LotPool` again. You need to call it once, store the result in a variable, and use it again for each time through the loop.

Answer (score 1):

In your winning sequence method you call LotPool() method. LotPool creates a new ArrayList every time.

I would refactor your code to initialize the 50 integers in the constructor and never do it again. Make LotPool() a simple getter method to return the arraylist.

Answer (score 0):

The single argument version of `Collections.shuffle` will produce a different random sequence each time you call it. In order to get repeatable results, you need to pass in your own random generator, and handle seeding appropriately.

You could do it something like this, though as noted by the other posters, this is still horribly inefficient.

```
public class LotSelection {

ArrayList<Integer> LotPool(long seed) {
    ArrayList<Integer> sequencedraw = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int i = 0; i < 49; i++) {
          sequencedraw.add(i);
    }
    Collections.shuffle(sequencedraw, new Random(seed));
    return sequencedraw;
}

int[] WinningSequence(long seed) {
    int[] WinningSequence = new int[6];
    int j = 0;
    while (j < 6) {
        WinningSequence[j] = LotPool(seed).get(j);
        j++;
    }
    return WinningSequence;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problem  in your WinningSequence method:

```
    WinningSequence[j] = LotPool().get(j);
```

You are getting the list everytime you add to your array. This will cause only the first element of the list to be fetched. You need to do this out of your loop just once.

Here is how you can update your WinningSequence method:

```
int[] WinningSequence() {
    int[] WinningSequence = new int[6];
    int j = 0;
    ArrayList<Integer> LotPool = LotPool().get(j)
    while (j < 6) {
        WinningSequence[j] = LotPool .get(j);
        j++;
    }
    return WinningSequence;
}
```